# Night Mode value not always being correctly considered on activity when started from a secondary process

Tags: android, android-appcompat, androidx, android-night-mode

The device/app current enviroment:

- the device is set to dark mode;
- the app is forcibly disabling the dark mode (`AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(MODE_NIGHT_NO)`).

---

When I launch the app from the device home page, everything works fine. The colors/images resources used are all correct.

But when I launch an Activity from the app from a secondary process, using a `PendingIntent`, the colors/images resources used are not all correct. Some `night-value` resources are undesirably being used.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        context,
        0,
        intent,
        0
);

pendingIntent.send();
```

> *Obs.: forcing an activity `recreate()` 5 seconds after the `onCreate` of the Activity, gets it fixed.*

Doing some research, I figured out that `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` version might have something to do with it. On version `1.1.0` the bug occurs, but on `1.2.0 (alpha 3)` it doesn't.

---

Is this a known Android bug?
Is there any workaround that is not using the alpha version of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`?